# compare table structure from ssms and table structure from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am performing delete operation. before that i am comparing weather column exist in the database. Is there any way to compare table structure from ssms and  table structure from XML.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL server. i have edited that